# Combobox exact match when the text entered is shorter than values in the combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a Combo Box of cities. One of the stored values is "Bronxville". The Combo Box accepts the value "Bronx". How can I stop this?

Thank you

Comment: Check the SelectedItem, not the Text. If a User enters text that has no matches in the ListItems or AutoComplete list, there's no Selection change (the `SelectedIndexChanged` or `SelectionChangeCommitted` events are not raised)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using WinForms. Change the `DropDownStyle` from `DropDown` to `DropDownList`.

From the documentation of [ComboBoxStyle Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle?view=net-5.0):

> - DropDown     1
>
>   Specifies that the list is displayed by clicking the down arrow and that the text portion is editable. This means that the user can enter a new value and is not limited to selecting an existing value in the list. When using this setting, the Append value of AutoCompleteMode works the same as the SuggestAppend value. This is the default style.

> - DropDownList     2
>
>   Specifies that the list is displayed by clicking the down arrow and that the text portion is not editable. This means that the user cannot enter a new value. Only values already in the list can be selected. The list displays only if AutoCompleteMode is Suggest or SuggestAppend.

> - Simple   0
>
>   Specifies that the list is always visible and that the text portion is editable. This means that the user can enter a new value and is not limited to selecting an existing value in the list.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but neither the DropDownList nor Simple leaves the feel of the DropDown. I was able to keep the DropDown style and accomplish the task by converting the case and using the Contains method when validating the user's input before updating as such:


 If Not cboCity.Items.Contains(CheckProperCase(cboCity.Text)) Then
  do something
 End If